# How to properly use DataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I've used ADO for a long time, but am a relative noob to ADO.Net, and am trying to figure out the best way to build a data service for my application.
When I want to query data, I can successfully build a SQL statement, instantiate a DataAdapter, fill a DataTable and return it. So far, so good.

The trouble is, my service needs to be able to return data from several tables (not at the same time). So I build a SQL statement and send it to the method which does the above steps, and everything works for each table I need data from.

In the common method, I instantiate the DataAdapter each time. I'm not bothering to set all commands, just the select command.

Now I'm wondering if this should be more extensible. Should I load the DataAdapter with all the commands (select, update, delete, insert) and keep it alive for as long as the service is alive? This would probably require 4 different adapters, one for each table I need to interact with.

This is for a single-user database, so there will be no worries of conflicts between users. Frankly, I could just execute SQL statements against the connection for adds, updates and deletes. I just want to get an idea of the best practice for doing this.

Thanks...

Comment: ADO.NET only keeps connections alive long enough to do the required query or CRUD operation. Then it closes so not sure what you mean in your comment about keeping stuff alive. Take a look at this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/904fck4k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I know that about connections. In fact, DataAdapter supposedly handles opening and closing them. I'm thinking of perpetuating the DataAdapters, not the connection. If I don't perpetuate the DAs, what's the point of setting the various commands in them? Is it best to just use them for selecting, and use straight SQL for updating, adding and deleting? Thanks...

Comment: I would look at using the Repository Pattern in conjunction with ADO.NET.

http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/04/ado-net-the-right-way/